# Arduino code does not fully execute, and won't reset

Tags: loops, arduino, microcontroller, execute

I'm programming a morse code translator/thing for my Arduino 101, however after I upload my code to my arduino, it only prints 10 values of long/short, when it should be printing about 24, as well as when I go to reset it it seems not to reset. I'm also confused as to how it does not print line 16, "tock". 
I'm not sure why the code isn't fully executing, it worked fine on a TI micro-controller (yes I did modify it when switching devices)

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

 pinMode(2,INPUT);
 pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
 int timeInterval =100;
 int totalTime=0;
 int i= 0;
 int dataPoints=24;
 int dash=3*timeInterval;
 int morse[dataPoints];
 int gapTime=0;
 int gap[dataPoints];
 Serial.print("tock");
for (i=1; i<dataPoints; ){
boolean buttonStatus = !digitalRead(2);
if (buttonStatus == HIGH){
  totalTime=totalTime+timeInterval;



  delay(timeInterval);
}
else{
gapTime=gapTime+timeInterval;


}

delay(timeInterval);
 if(buttonStatus==LOW)  {
   if (totalTime>dash){
    gap[i]=gapTime;

     Serial.print("Long"); 
     Serial.print(",");
     delay(1);
     totalTime=0;
     morse[i]=1;
     i++;
  gapTime=0;
    }
   else if(totalTime>0){
  gap[i]=gapTime;

     Serial.print("short");
      Serial.print(",");
      morse[i]=0;
    gapTime=0;
delay(1);
totalTime=0;
i++;}
 else{
delay(1);

 }
  }
 }
 Serial.println(morse[0]);
 Serial.println(gap[0]);
 Serial.println(morse[1]);
 Serial.println(gap[1]);
 Serial.println(morse[2]);
 Serial.println(gap[2]);
 Serial.println(morse[3]);
 Serial.println(gap[3]);
 Serial.println(morse[4]);
 Serial.println(gap[4]);
 Serial.println(morse[5]);
 Serial.println(gap[5]);
 Serial.println(morse[6]);
 Serial.println(gap[6]);
 Serial.println(morse[7]);
 Serial.println(gap[7]);
 Serial.println(morse[8]);
 Serial.println(gap[8]);
 Serial.println(morse[9]);
 Serial.println(gap[9]);
 Serial.println(morse[10]);
 Serial.println(gap[10]);
 Serial.println(morse[11]);
 Serial.println(gap[11]);
 Serial.println(morse[12]);
 Serial.println(gap[12]);
 Serial.println(morse[13]);
 Serial.println(gap[13]);
 Serial.println(morse[14]);
 Serial.println(gap[14]);
 Serial.println(morse[15]);
 Serial.println(gap[15]);
 Serial.println(morse[16]);
 Serial.println(gap[17]);
 Serial.println(morse[18]);
 Serial.println(gap[18]);
 Serial.println(morse[19]);
 Serial.println(gap[19]);
 Serial.println(morse[20]);
 Serial.println(gap[20]);
 Serial.println(morse[21]);
 Serial.println(gap[21]);
 Serial.println(morse[22]);
 Serial.println(gap[22]); 
 Serial.println(morse[23]);
 Serial.println(gap[23]);
 Serial.println(morse[24]);
 Serial.println(gap[24]);













int unit=5*timeInterval+1; 
for (i=1; i<(dataPoints-1);i++){
if (morse[i]==0&& gap[i+1]<unit && morse[i+1]==0 && gap[i+2]<unit &&      morse[i+2]==0 && gap[i+3]>unit){
 Serial.print("S");
 }if (morse[i]==1&& gap[i+1]<unit && morse[i+1]==1 && gap[i+2]<unit && morse[i+2]==1 && gap[i+3]>unit){
 Serial.print("O");

 }

 if (morse[i]==1 && gap[i+1]<unit && morse[i+1]==0 && gap[i+2]<unit && morse[i+2]==0 && gap[i+3]>unit){
 Serial.print("D");

}
if (morse[i]==0&& gap[i+1]<unit && morse[i+1]==1 && gap[i+2]<unit && morse[i+2]==0 && gap[i+3]>unit){
 Serial.print("R");

}


else{}
 }
 }

 void loop()
{

}
```

Comment: Some observations: `gap[0]` and `morse[0]` are uninitialised. `Serial.println(morse[24]); Serial.println(gap[24]);` exceeds the array bounds. And indexing `gap[]` or `morse[]` with `[i+2]` or `[i+3]` exceeds the array bounds. You can index an array of `n` elements from `[0] .. [n-1]`